# Question about dealing with invalid inputs of scanf

Tags: c, scanf

```
void placeg(game** g){
  //place marble;
  char row, col;
  char* buffer = NULL;
  printf("Please enter a move: ");
  scanf(" %c%c%s", &row, &col, buffer);
  // scanf(" %s", buffer);
  pos p = make_pos(charToInt((int)row),charToInt((int)col));
  place_marble((*g),p);
  board_show((*g)->b);
}
```

When I run the scanf function above in terminal, I expect to read and take in two char. For example, "AB" would be a valid terminal input. But in this case, I want my code to be able to detect invalid inputs such as "ABC" and inform the user accordingly. The following code above does not work for both valid and invalid inputs but I do not know why. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. In addition how would I potentially be able to detect other kinds of invalid inputs such as "A" or "" and be able to inform user accordingly?

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory for `buffer`.

Comment: In the case of ABC, I would discard all and re-prompt.

Comment: I'd just `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` and then analyze the received string in all the ways you want. Much simpler.

Comment: Echoing SHG, if you need to perform real input validation, don't use `scanf` - use `fgets` or similar to read in the entire input as text, and then parse it yourself.  Catching invalid input with `scanf` is an exercise in frustration.

Comment: Ditto, far simpler to test for the two characters (plus newline) in the required range. Simpler too, to discard the input when invalid

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgets` for input. Parse as needed. `sscanf` is but one option for parsing.
This uses A through I for valid row and 1 through 9 for valid column. That can be changed for actual requirements.
If `fgets` is used for input, use `fgets` for all input. Don't mix with `scanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    char input[128] = "";
    char row = 0;
    char col = 0;
    char nl = 0;
    int result = 0;

    do {
        printf ( "Enter row and col\n");
        if ( fgets ( input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
            if ( 3 == ( result = sscanf ( input, "%c%c%c", &row, &col, &nl))) {
                if ( '\n' != nl) {//not a newline
                    result = 0;
                }
                if ( row < 'A' || 'I' < row) {//A - I valid
                    result = 0;
                }
                if ( col < '1' || '9' < col) {//1 - 9 valid
                    result = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
            return 0;
        }
    } while ( 3 != result);

    printf ( "row: %c\ncol: %c\n", row, col);

    return 0;
}
```